# c++ weak_ptr expiring after dereference?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I'm new to smart pointers and I'm trying to wrap around my head why a weak_ptr would expire after a dereference operator. The code I used to test is here:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    weak_ptr<node> parent;
    shared_ptr<node> child;
    int val;
};

shared_ptr<node> foo()
{
    shared_ptr<node> a = make_shared<node>();
    shared_ptr<node> b = make_shared<node>();

    a->val = 30;
    b->val = 20;

    b->parent = a;
    a->child = b;

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<node> c = foo();
    node d = *foo();

    if (c->child->parent.expired())
    {
        cout << "weak ptr in c has expired." << endl;
    }

    if (d.child->parent.expired())
    {
        cout << "weak ptr in d has expired." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs `weak ptr in d has expired.`

I don't understand why when `d` uses the dereference operator, it expires. In regards to this, is there anyway to prevent it (other than not dereferencing it)?

---

I tried [as mrtnj suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38581461/3927257) by changing the `weak_ptr` in node to `shared_ptr` but I think I have a memory leak. I changed the `node` class to

```
struct node
{
    shared_ptr<node> parent;
    shared_ptr<node> child;
    int val;
};
```

and then modified the source code to add a `tryCreate` function.

```
void tryCreate()
{
    node d = *foo();
}
```

and then called it in my `main` such that my main looks like

```
int main()
{
    tryCreate();
    return 0;
}
```

I used Visual Studio 2015's memory profiling and noticed that there were only allocations and no deallocations. I changed `parent` into a `weak_ptr` and I see deallocations. Am I doing something wrong or is it indeed a  requirement to use `weak_ptr` in these cyclic condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `weak_ptr` expires when the last `shared_ptr` that refers to the object, is destroyed.

In your code that happens in the statement

```
node d = *foo();
```

Here `foo()` returns a `shared_ptr`, which is the last `shared_ptr` that refers to that object (the parent object of the two created by `foo`). And this `shared_ptr` is a temporary that's destroyed right there, after the derefencing. That reduces the reference count to 0 and the `weak_ptr` expires.

<del>Since the `shared_ptr` was the last one, the object is destroyed, which causes its child object to also be destroyed. Thus the later code that delves into these objects has undefined behavior.</del>

Since `d` contains a `shared_ptr` to the child node, the child node is not destroyed at this point, as noted by Miles Budnek in a comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the child node doesn't get destroyed, because the `child` pointer from the parent node allocated in `foo` gets copied to `d` before the original parent is destroyed at the end of the statement.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: You're right. Thanks! I'm in serious need of coffee (and sleep). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
node d = *foo();
```

`foo` returns a `shared_ptr` which is keeping the parent node allocated in `foo` alive.

You then copy the contents of that into `d` but do not store the shared_ptr, so that is destroyed at the end of the statement. There are now no shared_ptr instances referencing the node instance dynamically allocated in foo, so the weak pointer references to it are now expired.

The dereference isn't the problem: the problem is the failure to capture the `shared_ptr` being returned.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
node d = *foo();
```

you dereference shared_ptr, so `d` contains a copy of `node` which was created in foo in line:

```
shared_ptr<node> a = make_shared<node>();
```

this `a` will be destroyed just after `node d = *foo();`. This is because parent is only a weak_ptr inside node.

> In regards to this, is there anyway to prevent it (other than not dereferencing it)?

Not dereferencing seems to be good aproach.

<strike>You could switch from `weak_tr<node> parent;` to `shared_ptr<node> parent;`.</strike> Other solution would be to keep a global `shared_ptr<node> root;` which would keep a reference to your `a`. But It depends on what your code really is going todo.

Comment: Your memory will be deallocated when d destructor will be called, in your example this is end of main. This is a classic RAII. weak_ptr-s are mostly usefull when you need to store a shared_ptr in some object which should not prevent its destruction, and also for eliminating cyclic references of pointers.

Comment: @mrtnj I tried what you said by setting the parent into a `shared_ptr`. However, I noticed that there was a memory leak? Maybe I'm not getting my concepts correct. See the edit for what I did with your suggestion.

Comment: @silentwf you are right, that was a bad suggestion, I will remove it from answer (strike out). Have you considered using root reference? see example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a40dcc0178d75b